# How can i make wordpress author page template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make wordpress author page template like this website:

[https://alqabas.com/section/17-كتاب-وآراء](https://alqabas.com/section/17-%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create author.php file inside your theme root directory. Just created it and do your code inside it.